# excluding classes in spring boot DataMongoTest

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I have two spring data repository classes one each in `com.foo.cloud.landing.page.posts` and `com.foo.cloud.landing.page.personprofile` package. The test `PostRepositoryTest` for former is written in `com.foo.cloud.landing.page.posts` package in `src/test/main`. The test however doesn't honour `excludeFilter` of `@DataMongoTest` annotation

```
@DataMongoTest(properties = {
        "spring.data.mongodb.auto-index-creation=true",
        "spring.data.mongodb.database=landingpage_db_test",
        "spring.data.mongodb.port=17017",
        "foo.cloud.landing.page.mongodb.primary.uri=mongodb://localhost:17017/landingpage_db_test",
        "foo.cloud.landing.page.mongodb.secondary.uri=mongodb://localhost:17017/event-materializer_test",
        "logging.level.com.foo.cloud=DEBUG",
        "logging.level.kafka=WARN",
        "logging.level.org.apache=WARN",
        "logging.level.org.eclipse=WARN",
        "logging.level.org.springframework=DEBUG",
        "logging.level.root=INFO",
        "runtime-env=dev",
        "spring.application.name=landingpage",
        "spring.cloud.vault.enabled=false",
        "spring.cloud.config.enabled=false",
        "spring.main.banner-mode=off",
        "spring.mongodb.embedded.version=3.4.6"
}, excludeFilters = {@ComponentScan.Filter(classes = {PersonProfileRepository.class, LandingPageConfig.class, WebClientConfig.class, SecondaryMongoConfig.class})})
```

As you can see in the logs

```
2023-02-24 16:49:11.902  INFO 62636 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data MongoDB repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2023-02-24 16:49:11.903 DEBUG 62636 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Scanning for MongoDB repositories in packages com.foo.cloud.landing.page.personprofile, com.foo.cloud.landing.page.posts.
2023-02-24 16:49:11.911 DEBUG 62636 --- [           main] o.s.d.r.c.RepositoryComponentProvider    : Identified candidate component class: file [/Users/anadimisra/code/foo/landing_page/lp-microservice/target/classes/com/foo/cloud/landing/page/personprofile/PersonProfileRepository.class]
2023-02-24 16:49:11.918 DEBUG 62636 --- [           main] o.s.d.r.c.RepositoryComponentProvider    : Identified candidate component class: file [/Users/anadimisra/code/foo/landing_page/lp-microservice/target/classes/com/foo/cloud/landing/page/posts/PostRepository.class]
2023-02-24 16:49:11.926  INFO 62636 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 21 ms. Found 2 MongoDB repository interfaces.
```

My test then fails for missing beans that are needed by another bean that handles `@BeforeSaveEvent` for the `PersonProfileRepository`